# Is there a way to set a pragma disable warning for visual studio for an entire solution?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pragma

Is there a way to set a pragma disable warning for visual studio for an entire solution?

Comment: It's a good idea to use a solution-wide **property sheet** (.vsprops file). This sheet contains multiple settings so you can manage them centrally.
 ("debug" and "release" configurations are implemented as property sheets as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [/w compiler switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y(v=vs.140).aspx) for per-project suppression.  I'm not aware of any way to do it solution wide without selecting all projects and adding it to the command-line for each project (which can be done in one operation).